# What is meant by +x in the expression ${GC_TUNE+x}

Tags: bash, shell

I see the following lines in a [solr shell script](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/bin/solr#L1819-L1820):

```
  if [ -z ${GC_TUNE+x} ]; then
    GC_TUNE=('-XX:NewRatio=3'
```

I do get the purpose of the above statement but not very sure what is meant by `${GC_TUNE+x}`

Comment: The folks who wrote that code probably meant `[ -z "${GC_TUNE+x}" ]`, by the way.

Comment: ...without the quotes, `[ -z ]` is interpreted as `[ -n -z ]` -- as in, it's asking whether `-z` is an empty string or not (since `-n` is the implicit operator in *any* case where only one argument is passed to `test`), rather than whether `${GC_TUNE+x}` evaluates to an empty string or not, when `GC_TUNE` is empty. Since the result is true, the end result is still what the original author meant, but it's the right result for a surprising/misleading reason, whereas with the quotes in place, it returns the right result *for the right reason*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `GC_TUNE` is set, then the value will be x. Otherwise it will be empty.

I like to keep [this page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value) bookmarked for just such an occasion!

Here's a quick demo:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo begin
unset foo
echo ${foo+bar} # unset, so this expands to nothing
foo=baz
echo ${foo+bar} # is set, so it expands to the value of the variable
echo end
```

Output:

```
begin

baz
end
```

Comment: This is pretty strange. echo $foo also expands to nothing. Then why add +bar in there? Basically, I get the same output even if I remove +bar from all places above

Comment: So you can tell the difference between `unset foo` and `foo=""`. It may look the same to human eyes, but could need to be treated differently for some reason.

Comment: Also, `${foo+x}` is guaranteed to expand to either the empty string or `x` -- there are fewer corner cases there than you could have just expanding `$foo` (which, for an arbitrary value of `foo`, could contain whitespace, wildcards, etc). If you're writing your code in a safe and sane manner (quoting everywhere appropriate &c) that shouldn't matter, but... not everyone does.

Comment: @miken32 correctly notes the difference between `unset foo` (an unset variable) and `foo=""` (set but empty). For example try `unset a; b=${a+foo}; echo "$b"` compared to `a=""; b=${a+foo}; echo "$b"`